# Flutter) I wonder how to remove items from the created list by pressing the button

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I press the button to add a ListTile widget to the list and output it to the ListViewBuilder.  And I want to delete the list by pressing the delete button on each list.

```
  List<ListTile> _todoList = [];
```

Add List Button

```
 TextButton.icon(
  onPressed: () {
     //I wrote the text in a TextField in the Dialog Widget.
     //And add ListTile widget to list
     _todoList.add(_addListTile(_textController.text));
  }
```

Output list

```
  ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
         return _todoList[index];
      },
              
      itemCount: _todoList.length),
```

This is a widget that is added to the list. And I want to delete the index of the list by pressing the button on the list tile.

```
  _addListTile(String text) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(text),
      //menu 
      trailing: PopupMenuButton(
        // icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        itemBuilder: (context) {
          return [const PopupMenuItem<int>(value: 0, child: Text('Remove'))];
        },
        //Cliked menu 
        onSelected: (item) {
          switch (item) {
            case 0:
              return print('Remove List');
              // return _todoList.remove();
          }
        },
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
```

How can I delete the list with the delete button on this ListTile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can put a `key` value to each `ListTile` object to identify which ListTile is the one you want to delete everytime you generate it in your `_addListTile()` function like following.

```dart
  _addListTile(String text) {
    // You can have anything to be the unique value. Here, I just used the current time.
    // I can't say this is the best option.
    final key = ValueKey(DateTime.now().toString()); 

    return ListTile(
      key: key,
      title: Text(text),
      //menu 
      trailing: PopupMenuButton(
        // icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
        itemBuilder: (context) {
          return [const PopupMenuItem<int>(value: 0, child: Text('Remove'))];
        },
        //Cliked menu 
        onSelected: (item) {
          switch (item) {
            case 0:
              print('Remove List');
              return _todoList.removeWhere((e) => e.key == key);
          }
        },
      ),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
```

I hope it'd work for you.